# How to add location text character by character like in action movies?

Tags: kdenlive

For a video I want to add text character by character, including the beep-beep-beep alike sound, like common action movies do this when switching to a new location. Obviously, I don't know how this is called and if it is military related, so I hope you know what I mean.

I already figured out how to generally add text, but I found no option or animation to introduce it character by character. Alternatively I would have to manually insert character by character; but this would be difficult to align properly (not vertically, but horizontally (proper character spacing)).

I though of using the subtitle feature for this. But if there is a more elegant solution, I would prefer to not using subtitles.

---

The software is Kdenlive 19.12.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.

I do video editing occasionally only; I am sorry for any misconceptions, wrong wording, etc in my description, therefore.

---

Edit:

- Unfortunately I am unable to find an example on youtube currently
- Maybe there is an effect that is able to fade the text in from the left to the right as an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way:

1. Add title text to video
2. Add the `Rotoscope` effect to the title
3. At timeline start of text: draw the rotoscope shape around the text (see below)
4. At timeline end of text: add keyframe and move the shape behind the text (see below)
5. Set the effect mode to `Luma`
6. Add the `Cairo Blend` composition to the title
7. Set the gradient mode to `Add`

Now the title text should appear from left to right. It does not appear character by character, but this is ok.

The rotoscope effect is quite mighty - this video teached me how to use it:

Additionally I found this cool sound, which is quite exactly I was looking for:
https://freesound.org/people/Sky_Motion/sounds/416777/